# Add $more_link_text parameter to the_excerpt()

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, the-content, excerpt

this `filter` is on the Wordpress Codex …

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> &hellip; </a>';
}
```

This works perfect, however I wonder if it is also possible to create a filter that extends `the_excerpt()` with the same parameter like `the_content()` where it is possible to set the "more-link-text" as parameter?

So I wonder how I can achieve this …

`the_excerpt('custom more link')``

This would be especially useful for me because I have multiple custom-post-types where I always use `the_excerpt()` as teasers. Since those custom-post-types have various contexts and meanings it would be nice to have different "more-links" at the end …

Is this somehow possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_post_type`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_type/)

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

    function new_excerpt_more($more) {
        global $post;

        $post_type = get_post_type($post);
        switch( $post_type ):
            case 'event':
               $teaser = '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> More events </a>';
               break;

            case 'post':
               $teaser = '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> &hellip; </a>';
               break;

            default
                $teaser = '';
        endswitch;

        return $teaser;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is ok as well. I just thought there is a way to extend this function with this parameter - would be way more "semantic" to code.